# Database delete issue

Tags: iphone

I have this type of data stored as the BookMark in the BookMarks table.....this type of data (which is having ' in between the string) is not removed from the database....
Else other data are properly removed.

Then what is the solution of this type of issue.

**Query**:-->

```
       Delete from BookMarks where name='Bimbo's 365 Club'

       Delete from BookMarks where name='Slim's'
```

**it gives me**:-->

```
       near "s": syntax error
```

Both of the above are the examples where problem occurs.

Please suggest me the appropriate solution of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use backslash in front of the single quote as \' to indicate a single quote in your value.
i.e.

```
 Delete from BookMarks where name='Bimbo\'s 365 Club'
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, but the problem is that, he is getting the values from db, so each time befor delete he need to replace the ' with\', this will inc the coding.

Comment: escape sequence is the only way to override this kind of problems. Using " instead of ' will cause problem if the text contains "

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ' use " to indicate the value,

Ex: `Delete from BookMarks where name="Bimbo's 365 Club"`